# How to sqoop rowversion /timestmap/binary SQL Server datatypes into hive using sqoop

Tags: sql-server, hive, sqoop

While sqooping `binary` datatype or `timestamp` (which is now `rowversion`) datatype from SQL Server to hive tables, Sqoop is throwing an error.

Used option

```
--map-column-hive DATAROWVERSION=string
```

to convert timestamp or binary to a string.

But output is not exactly same.

`0x0000000001B9CC75` is converted to `00 00 00 00 01 B9 CC 75` in hive.

Is there any other way to get exact value into hive?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `--map-column-hive DATAROWVERSION=binary`?

Comment: yes, tried binary format. Output in hive looks like `�M4�M4�W�}�}`

Comment: The output of a binary field is a strange concept. I mean, it's literally a bunch of 0s and 1s with no extra information about how it should be interpreted. If the datatype is string, it can represent the bytes as ascii or unicode characters, but it's a bit uncertain how a binary will display to you unless you specifically format it as something. That weird m4m4 thing could well be a representation of the same binary. The exact value of that binary is not 0x0000000001B9CC75 because that is a hexadecimal representation of the actual binary value.